# Convert following Excel Formulae to Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

Could someone help me to convert following excel formulae to dax:

=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,Q:Q,Q1,C:C">="&C1-25)

Comment: It is not that such to apply excel formula into Dax, please provide example for your data in order to help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the third IF in that Excel function is not correct. Assuming you want this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,Q:Q,Q1,C:C,">=25")
```

You can try this out:

```
Count Result = 
   CALCULATE( 
      COUNT('TableName'[ColumnA]),
      ALLEXCEPT( 'TableName', 'TableName'[ColumnA], 'TableName'[ColumnQ]),
      'TableName'[ColumnC] >= 25
   )
```

If it was not what you meant by that, maybe it could help giving you an idea of how you can achieve it.